# Error: Duplicate declaration in Playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright

**When I run the command I am getting Error: Duplicate declaration in Playwright**

`npx playwright test -g 'Bpay1' --headed --project=chromium`

**I am getting the following error**

Error: Duplicate declaration "test"
24 | });
25 |

> 26 | import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
> |          ^^^^
> 27 |
> 28 | test('test', async ({ page }) => {
> 29 |   test.setTimeout(300000);``

**This is the code**

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('Bpay1', async ({ page }) => {
  test.setTimeout(300000);
  await page.goto('https://www.test.com');
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Section tag #1').click();
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Section tag #1').press('Control+a');
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Section tag #1').fill('inapptest');
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'UPDATE' }).click();
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Message us' }).click();
  await page.getByRole('textbox', { name: 'Enter text here' }).click();  
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Enter text here').click();
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Enter text here').fill('payment not processed');
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Enter text here').press('Enter');
  await page.waitForTimeout(15000);
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sending' }).click();
  await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
  await page.locator('#lp_line_8').getByRole('button', { name: 'BPAY' }).click();
  await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Yes, close conversation' }).click();
});
```

Comment: It seems there are two tests with the title "Bpay1".Is that correct?